# How to show each table record separately in rdlc

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting, reportviewer, rdlc

I am designing a rdlc report.

Currently the report is displaying as

[image: table style]

Basically it is a grouped date 
The Schema of group is as

- `Work Description` and `No of hours` are grouped by `project id`
- Then `project id` is grouped by `date of work`

I want to show all the `grouped records by date` separately. Like:

[image: Wanted Design of report]

So how do i achive this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Add a group footer row to the group on your date column. Then merge all of the cells in that row together. (Select all of the cells, right-click, and select "Merge cells").

Then you need to turn off all of the border lines for the merged cell. This is done a bit differently depending on the version of SSRS you're developing in. But it can always be done from the toolbar at the top.

The button you're looking for looks like a square sectioned into quarters. Next to it will be the options for the colour, thickness, and style of the borders. Clicking the box icon will drop-down a menu where you can select "No border" which will set all of the border styles for each side of the cell to "None".

If you find you still have a border on the left and right side of the cell it is because there is a border around the tablix control itself. Turn off that border and you should get the effect you want.

You may need to mess with the border properties of some of the nearby cells if you're having issues. I've always found working with the cell borders in SSRS to be a bit fiddly but you the design you're after is certainly possible.

---

Another way to achieve this would be to nest the table control inside of a list control and group the list control on the date. Add a bit of space below the table before the edge of the list. That way when the list repeats the table there is a space between them.

The table will only show records that are in the current group for the list control so you don't need to add any additional filtering on the table.

Comment: could you please elaborate it more.

Comment: Does that explain it better?

Comment: Mike i tried as you said but inserting footer row group is not giving the desired design

Comment: Cell borders are often difficult to deal with in SSRS. What trouble are you having? I've also updated the answer with an easier method for achieving the result you're after.